# In Magento 2 Product Update via Import CSV file

Tags: magento2.3, csv, bundled-product, import-products

*Need to update the product data via CSV file through import action.*

***I am facing an issue to display the bundle product in front-end of the website after updating the product via import action.***

> **Here are the steps which I have followed:**
>
> 1. Creating a new product (simple product and bundle product) in the admin panel
> 2. Go to System -> Data Transfer -> Export and export it.
> 3. Open the exported CSV file and update/change the price or any attribute value in it
> 4. Now, go to Sytem -> Data Transfer -> Import and Imported Successfully.
> 5. The Products are not showing in front end

```
  Current result:  The product page showing as "404 error message Page not found"
```

Comment: you done indexing? or check qty and in stock options

Comment: yes, I have done indexing, updating attributes via mass action. Cross checked qty and in stock options all are good.  when we delete that product and update import csv file, its working fine. Similarly while duplicating the same product its working fine too.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Frontend or backend?

Comment: @maurisourceweb, In frontend we are getting page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this, it seems that we have to go to the bundled product in admin and click save it in order to have it properly pass through the save action following csv post-import.